# Solar charging an Ebike

Tags: batteries, charging, solar-energy

I would like to charge an Ebike battery (48 V) with solar panels (12 V out). I would prefer not to use inverter to 240 V (which current charger requires). Can I connect MPPT directly to EBike battery?

How to build a charging unit which most efficiently transfers solar 12 V output to 48 V battery?

I would then like to operate 36 V power tools with the same 48 V battery - could I use a step-down modulator of some sort?

Comment: *Can I connect MPPT directly to EBike battery?* **NO**, the Ebike battery **MUST** be charged through a proper **charge controller** which I'm guessing your "MPPT" is not. *How to build a charging...* That isn't something that can be answered here, how good are your circuit design skills? Even for an experienced ciruit designer, this will not be that easy to design. *Power tools...* That's **asking for trouble** your tools might need more power than most converters can handle. Power tools need high currents which few step down converters can handle.

Comment: There are commercial MPPT step up converters which can charge your 48 V Li-ion battery, assuming your BMS is up for the job otherwise. Go for one of those or 12 -> 240 V inverter and original charger if you have powerful enough panels.

Comment: Genasun GVB-8-Li-56.8V comes to mind but you’ll need to make sure your BMS will prevent anything bad from happening or you will have an explosive fire.